# How to get next and previous date on button Click from UmmalquraCalendar?

Tags: android, date, onclick

The issue is simple, i want get next and previous date from UmmalQuraCalendar on button click and show it in textview (settext). Its easy to show current date in textview, but next and previous im unable to get. Below example code from which i want get them:

```
        UmmalquraCalendar ca = new UmmalquraCalendar();
        ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        ca.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        ca.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
        ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String dtIslamic = ca.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH)+"-"+ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mHijriDate.setText(dtIslamic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.YEAR / MONTH and so on are int arrays (int[]), so doing `ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1`; should give you the previous day and +1 the next one

Comment: Sorry, but i dont understand, its UmmalQuraCalendar, not simple Calendar

Comment: UmmalQuraCalendar is its library?

Comment: `String dtIslamic = ca.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH)+"-"+(ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1)+"-"+ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);` and `String dtIslamic = ca.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH)+"-"+(ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1)+"-"+ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);` this is what Apbln wrote you. Сopy and study carefully. Pay attention to it: **ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +/- 1)**

Comment: i understood. but the date change only 1 time. if i click on nextdate button several times, itsnot changing, not +1 again.

Comment: @alizulfuqar, Just you need to save the day in variable _int_, and use it instead of this **(ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +/- 1)**. If you can’t do it, I can write the code tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, would be very helpful.

Comment: @alizulfuqar, I want to see you code. Send me a link from GitHub

Comment: @alizulfuqar, you need to change the logic of your code. Write to my mail.